# "Having influence" in perfect tense

Tags: present-perfect

I chatted on IRC and stumbled upon such a nice sentence:

> On the opposite, Tom has been a good influence on my life since I met him.

For me it means that *Tom* is an *influence*, instead of *Tom having influence*. So I'd rephrase that as:

> On the opposite, Tom has had a good influence on my life since I met him.

However then a native speaker said that the first sentence is more natural to him.

Which one is correct here?

Comment: "On the opposite" sounds very foreign to my ear.

Comment: Ditto Robusto. A native speaker would not say, "on the opposite" but more likely "on the other hand" for a mild paradox, or "on the contrary" for a negation.

Comment: I agree with Robusto. I'd use "on the contrary".  The rest sounds fine either way.

Comment: We don't have OP's full context, but possibly it's one where most of us would say "**Quite** *the opposite - Tom has had a good influence...*"

Comment: The earlier sentence of another user was: "Tom, you're encouraging him to procrastinate a lot."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with others, I agree both OP's sentences are "valid", but neither existing answer seems to address the issue of whether either is "preferred". The mention of "perfect tense" in the title is irrelevant - usage is unaffected by *"has been/has had"* (present perfect) or *"was/had"* (simple past).

The issue under consideration is just *"had"* vs *"was a good/bad influence"*. From Google Books:

- *"he had a bad influence on me"* - 5 instances.
- *"I had a bad influence on her"* - 1 instance.
- *"she had a good influence on him"* - 6 instances.

but

- *"he was a bad influence on me"* - 392 instances.
- *"I was a bad influence on her"* - 1120 instances.
- *"she was a good influence on him"* - 131 instances.

I think that's enough to establish that if we're talking about "influence" as something that causes positive/negative changes *in the person being influenced*, we normally speak of **being** *an influence*.

---

It's different if we're talking about "influence" where the moral development of the influenced party isn't central - for example, trying to persuade someone to do something. There, constructions like *"he **has** influence with/over them"* dominate. All variations of "*he **was** an influence/influential with/over them*" are either unusual or unknown.

---

TL;DR: You **are** an influence on [the moral development of] others (it's an ongoing state). Whereas more commonly you **have** influence you bring to bear on specific occasions, to persuade someone to adopt a particular course of action.

Answer (score 8):

Both are correct, in that influence is either the "capacity to be a compelling force" (Tom has *had* this), or "a person or thing that exerts influence" (Tom has *been* this).

Answer (score 2):

**Influence** may denote "a person who exerts influence" - a person or thing having influence.

> My parents considered my friend to be a bad influence on me.